# "WiFi is disabled by hardware switch" on Asus X75 VD notebook?

Tags: wireless, asus

How can I enable WiFi on Ubuntu 13.10?

I'm using an Asus X75 Vd notebook (RaLink Wireless) and I want to use WiFi but I'm getting a message stating "WiFi is disabled by hardware switch".

How do I enable it?

Comment: Most likely you need to check your manual. There is either a slider on the machine itself, or you need to turn it on in BIOS or there is a combination of keys that activate wireless (something like Fn+F2).

Answer (score 0):

I had problems getting my wi-fi working on my Laptop ASUS X75VB-TY038D, Intel Core i5-3230M. I succeed by following [these steps at the Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, **and provide the link for reference**.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's resolved by removing network manager and installing wicd for it.

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
```